# Using Google NodeJS speech-to-text with audio from client microphone

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-to-text, getusermedia, google-speech-api

I am trying to use google's speech-to-text nodeJS library (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech) and stream audio from the client's microphone input with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia.

I was able to *stream microphone with sox to nodejs-speech* streamingRecognize and it was working. 
I was also able to *stream audio from the client side and make and pipe it to the speaker on the server side*. **However, when I try to pipe it to streamingRecognize it doesn't recognize any word.**

**Server-side**

```
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,

        languageCode: languageCode,
    },
    interimResults: true,
    //singleUtterance: false
};
let recognizeStream = speechClient
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('data', data => {
        console.log(data);
        process.stdout.write(
            data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0] ?
            `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n` :
            `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`
        )
    });
io.on("connection", function (client) {
    client.on("userSpeaking", function (data) {
        if (recognizeStream !== null) {
            recognizeStream.write(new Uint8Array(data));
        }
    });
});
```

**Client-side**

```
function convertFloat32ToInt16(buffer) {
    let l = buffer.length;
    let buf = new Int16Array(l);
    while (l--) {
        buf[l] = Math.min(1, buffer[l]) * 0x7FFF;
    }
    return buf.buffer;
}
AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new AudioContext();
processor = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
processor.connect(context.destination);
context.resume();

function microphoneProcess(e) {
  var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  var left16 = convertFloat32ToInt16(left);
  socket.emit('userSpeaking', left16);
}
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: false,
    audio: true
  }, {
    type: 'audio',
    sampleRate: 16000,
    desiredSampleRate: 16000,
    audioBitsPerSecond: 16000,
    mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    globalStream = stream;
    input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    input.connect(processor);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
      microphoneProcess(e);
    };
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: i dont think 'streaming.requests' work yet with GCSpeech on node... https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/recognize.v1p1beta1.js#L71  this example < V1 beta> works on node and works from mic input to an audio blob that you could post to your server from the client where the mic gets input. f But this action can be done ONLY when the audio input is complete. Its not a stream interface which AFAIK still requires a native app with a build that supports  the gRPC and protoBuffer stack.

Comment: @RobertRowntree it works for me if the mic input is directly in the nodejs code. I tried it with node-record-lpcm16 and it works (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/recognize.js#L440). 
however it doesnt work if I try to send it from the client side.

I am wondering if it is related to me using mono audio instead of stereo.

Comment: gcspeech is  all mono but you appear to be getting 'left' chan from stereo. i dont know. i also record opus-mono in a js client, save the recording and use gCS to recognize the audio ... FWIW i post the opus blob to my 'app.js' < express back end > and use the cloud speech client from there. But i just convert the opus binary to a bin64 string before sending to google.  It works but its clunky.

Comment: @RobertRowntree Can you share some code please.